# Long words are flowing out of the box - How to prevent?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a styled `div` where I need to add a long text. I have a maximum width ( `100px` ) and I need to "make text go down". Now I can't find a solution for my problem: in case of long text, it goes out of the box. I don't have a height problem so it should take any size required.

This is my code:

```
<style>  
    .infobox { 
        -moz-background-clip: padding;     
        -webkit-background-clip: padding;  
        background-clip: padding-box;      
        border: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px; 

        padding: 30px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;

        top: 100px;
        left: 200px; 
    } 
</style> 

<div class="infobox"> LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEXT :)</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`word-wrap: break-word;` should help.

- [Supported in every browser that matters - caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap)
- [Read about it on CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/)
- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d59hM/) - thanks to @Nacereddine

Comment: I was going for `overflow:auto;` but your solution is much more elegant. Anyway, here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d59hM/) of this solution.

Comment: @Nacereddine Thanks, if you don't mind, I include it in my answer.